# Javascript Timer with different images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a JS timer script that counts down from 20 seconds

```
var count = 0;
var speed = 1000;

countdown = setInterval(

        function(){

        jQuery("#countdown").html(count);

        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        count--;
        }

,speed);
```

Is there a way to dynamically change the src of an image when the timer gets to a certain point? Eg:

```
if (count >= 0 && count <= 10) {
 img.src = "2.png"
}

if (count >= 11 && count <= 20) {
 img.src = "1.png"
}
```

When the user clicks a button it adds 5 to the count on the timer:

```
jQuery('#add').click(function() {
    if(count >= 0 && count <= 18)   {count = count + 6}
```

So when the value goes above 11 again the image src should revert back to 1.png

Basically its a script that changes a image's src according to the value of timer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure javascript you would do it somewhat like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/e54L3/

HTML:

```
<button>Buttan</button>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
"use strict";
(function(document) {
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter'), 
        button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
        // Added one extra to count to compensate for the one immediate countdown...
        count = 6, speed = 1000, countAddStep = 5, timeout,
        func = function () {
            count--;
            counter.innerHTML = count;
            if(count !== 0) {
                timeout = setTimeout(func, speed);
            }
        };

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Add the countstep to count
        count = count+countAddStep;
        counter.innerHTML = count;
        // Restart the timeout if needed.
        if (count === countAddStep) {
            // Add one for the one immediate countdown
            count++;
            func();
        }
    });

    // Start the timeout with 1 second (1000 ms) intervals
    func();
} (document));
```

This would be a proper way to do it if you're just starting to learn javascript. If you need to implement something for an existing application/website you're likely to have a library like jQuery at your disposal, which would simplify things a bit and make it more cross browser compatible.

<strike>I'm sure people will post jQuery examples as well...</strike> Actually [here is the jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/e54L3/1/). Knowing proper js is more important.

You can make the timer an image, I didn't have images so I kept it to html.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the src of a image is easy with Jquery.

```
var newSrc=".....  " ; // new img path
$('#img1').attr('src',newSrc ); //changing the image
```

EDIT:

```
jQuery('#add').click(function() {

if(count >= 0 && count <= 18)   
{
   if(count==11)
  {
     var newSrc=".....  " ; // new img path
     $('#img1').attr('src',newSrc ); //changing the image 
  }

  count = count + 6
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain javascript, you can give the image an id and then access the image using

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src="newimage.png";
```

and update it to the desired image.

Answer (score 0):

You can change every attribute with jQuery like this:

```
var count = 0;
var speed = 1000;

countdown = setInterval(function(){
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        count--;
        $("#countdown").prop("src", count + ".png");
}
,speed);
```

But probably you'd prefer to have one big image with sprites and change `background-position` style instead of `src` to avoid delays when new image is loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that you call at the end of each interval and also on click after incrementing the count.
Something like this:

```
function validateImg(){
    var $img = $('#imgID');
    if (count >= 0 && count <= 10 && $img.attr('src') !='2.png') {
        $img.attr('src','2.png');
    }

    if (count >= 11 && count <= 20 && $img.attr('src') !='1.png') {
        $img.attr('src','1.png');
    }
}
```

This way you will only change the img if the count is in the correct interval